# Chart more than one group with LogParser 2.2?

Tags: sql, csv, logparser

Let's say I have a simple data set in csv like:

```
Time,User
01/22/2014 15:23:01,Bob
01/22/2014 16:24:01,John
01/22/2014 16:27:01,Bob
01/22/2014 17:23:01,Bob
```

Can I generate a box plot with Time on the x-axis (quantized to the hour), user on the y-axis, and sum(*) on the z-axis?  So essentially the number of 'hits' per user per hour.

No matter how I try this, LogParser appears to only allow me one category (I have two, time and user).  I get an error that either the time or the user is non-numerical.

Also, I don't know the full list of users... otherwise I could split out the 'sum(*)' to sum each user separately.

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately LogParser only supports one single categoric axis (the X axis), so the answer is no.